# Docker container communication restrictions

Tags: docker

My setup is based on running two Docker containers, one with an API and the other with a DB.
This methodology makes it possible that both containers have an exposed port to web services.

But what I want is that the DB container (toolname-db) can only be exposed to the API container (toolname-api). This makes sure that the DB is not not exposed to web services directly.

How do I have to alter my setup in order to make sure what I want is possible?

Currently I use the following commands:

```
sudo docker build -t toolname .
sudo docker run -d -p 3333:3333 --name=toolname-db mdillon/postgis
sudo docker run -it -p 4444:4444 --name=toolname-api --network=host -d toolname
```

Comment: Where are the Web services running?  Why do you have the API service running on the host network?

Comment: They run on an Ubuntu server. Good question, I thought this was the way to do it. What do you recommend?

Comment: `But what I want is that the DB container (toolname-db) can only be exposed to the API container` - put those two in same network and also use docker-compose to make life easier for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A container will only be reachable from outside Docker space if it has published ports.  So you need to remove the `-p` option from your database container.

For the two containers to be able to talk to each other they need to be on the same [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).  Docker's default here is for compatibility with what's now a very old networking setup, so you need to manually create a network, though it doesn't need any special setting.

Finally, you don't need `--net host`.  That disables all of Docker's networking setup; port mappings with `-p` are disabled, and you can't communicate with containers that don't themselves have ports published.  (I usually see it recommended as a hack to work around hard-coded `localhost` connection strings.)

That leaves your final setup as:

```
sudo docker build -t toolname .
sudo docker network create tool
sudo docker run -d --net=tool --name=toolname-db mdillon/postgis
sudo docker run -d --net=tool -p 4444:4444 --name=toolname-api toolname
```

As @BentCoder suggests in a comment, it's very common to use Docker Compose to run multiple containers together.  If you do, [it creates a network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) which can save you a step.

Comment: Still, I am not able to connect from my API to my DB. When I use the following command in the API it refuses to connect. For localhost I also tried the docker network and the toolname-db. The command line from my API to my DB is as follows:

postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname

Any idea how to enable this connection?

Comment: Within that Docker network, `toolname-db` is a valid hostname and you should include it in your connection string.  Configuring this as an environment variable is common.

Comment: Unfortunately both the following options failed. `postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@toolname-db/dbname` and `postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@toolname-db:5432/dbname` still return with a connection refused from within the API. Is there something I forget?

Comment: The other common case is, if you try to start up both things at exactly the same time, the database can take 30-60 seconds come up.  You will get an error like "connection refused" but not an error like "cannot resolve hostname".

Comment: Thanks, you are right, just waiting a while fixed it all.